# Issue when camera is open [Expo]

Tags: react-native, expo

The app crashed when the function is executed, but in development mode works fine.

I'm using Expo SDK and I need take a picture from the camera app

```
takePhoto = async () => {
        const status = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA, Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
        const result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [4, 3],
            // base64: true
        });

        if (!result.cancelled && result.type === 'image') {
            this.setState({ image: result.uri, bottomsheet: false })
        }
        console.log(result);
    }
```

I expected the camera app working fine but instead I ged a restart of the app :s